# parsing through file to print duplicate words and print on adjacent line - bash script

Tags: bash, text-processing

Example list:

```
goodbye  
goodbye  
hello  
hi  
hi  
hi  
no
```

Expected output:

```
goodbye goodbye  
hello  
hi hi hi   
no
```

I'd like to print the even the 'unlike' word as well, just on a separate individual line. But any matching on the same line. Can 'tr' be used with a loop?

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while read line
 do
     if [$var == $var]
     then
        echo $var | tr -s ' '

        else
        echo $var | tr '\n' 

     fi

 done < foo.txt
```

Comment: Do you need a solution in `bash`, or `sed`/`awk`/etc. are also an option?

Comment: What does `I'd like to print the even the 'unlike' word as well` mean?

Comment: @EdMorton sorry.. meant words that aren't duplicated to be printed as well; just on a separate line.

Comment: @randomir i do need it in bash, if possible. i've used sort to sort the words alphabetically, so that they're in order. just needed to figure a way a loop to group the duplicates into one line. all other solutions i've looked at online include removing the duplicates. but i want to keep them and group them.

Comment: @Mindy have a look then at the solution in bash below.

Comment: What do you mean by "in bash"? Do you mean only using shell builtins (i.e. no sort, sed, grep, tr, awk, etc.) or something else? Why wouldn't you just use awk?

Answer (score 0):

**awk** one-liner:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s",(NR==1? "": (r==$1? FS:ORS)),$0; r=$1 }END{ print "" }' file
```

The output:

```
goodbye goodbye
hello
hi hi hi
no
```

Comment: @Mindy, `tr` command is not for comparing adjacent strings, it's for simple translation

Answer (score 0):

using **awk**

If all the matching words are in consecutive lines (as in your input) then you can use this solution.

```
$awk 'FNR==1{a=$0; ORS=" "} a!=$0{a=$0; $0=RS $0} END{printf RS}1' file

goodbye goodbye 
hello 
hi hi hi 
no
```

Comment: this will add an excessive newline at start of the output and miss the ending newline after `no` word

Comment: @Mindy: No Mindy. `tr` is just for translate not for text processing.

Comment: @batMan, now it remains for you to get rid of *excessive newline at start of the output*

Comment: @batMan - OK. i should've figured that. I've already sorted the words a-z, but was curious to know if it could be listed onto 1 line using a bash.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, pure `bash`, solution that expands on your attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=1
while read word; do
    if (( first )); then
        printf "%s" "$word"
        first=0
    else
        if [[ $word == $prev ]]; then
            printf " %s" "$word"
        else
            printf "\n%s" "$word"
        fi
    fi
    prev="$word"
done < foo.txt
echo
```

For each `word` read from your input file, we check if it's the same as the previous word printed; if yes - we continue to print in the same line; if no - we break the sequence and print the new word in the new line.

The first word is always printed without any prefix (space/newline), so we handle that special case via the `first` variable.

The `printf` command is used instead of `echo` because it has a nicer control of output (format), but `echo -n` could have been used too.